# How to find specific text from the column and remove only that text in multiple rows one by one

Tags: vba, excel

Hy Experts, I am facing problem in a macro. I have two sheets one is called "WalMart" its look like this..

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F6Lnm.png)

the another sheet is "List"

it is looks like this...
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F6Lnm.png)

Now if you notice that in the second sheet there is column name with "Wal-Mart Banned Words" that has different words in every cell. I want a macro that could search the word written the banned list column like if I write in J cell no 3 as Delux it should be search from the other search from product column in all rows and delete where it found. The remaining text should be same but the word "Delux" will be deleted....

Could it possible....

I am trying this recorded macro....

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ImSip.png)

Comment: a) Don't show us code in an image. Frankly, it is rude and insulting that you think we have nothing better to do with our time than retype your code in order to test it. You can paste the relevant portion of the code into your question through an [edit] then select the code portion and tap ctrl+K.to format it into a code block. b) You actually didn't even post the correct image so that's one less thing to delete when you [edit] your question to include a [mcve]. c) All of this information I've just recited to you is readily available in this site's [Help] section.

Answer (score 1):

```
Option Compare Text
Sub StackOverflow()


Dim banned_words() As String
Dim counter As Integer

Range("J2").Activate

counter = 0

Do While ActiveCell <> ""
    ReDim Preserve banned_words(counter + 1)
    banned_words(counter) = ActiveCell.Value
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Activate
    counter = counter + 1
Loop

Range("N2").Activate

Do While ActiveCell <> ""
    For Each bad_word In banned_words
        ActiveCell.Value = Replace(ActiveCell.Value, bad_word, "")
    Next bad_word
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Activate
Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: I might have thrown the 'bad_words in as `banned_words = application.transpose(range(cells(2, "J"), cells(rows.count, "J").end(xlup)).value2)` but I think you've got the OP off to a good start.